# Should I create this accessors

Tags: php, accessor

So I got this example layout.

```
private $_getMilk() = '';

public function getMilk():string {
    return $this->_milk;
}

public function setMilk(string $milk) {
    $this->_milk = $milk;
}
```

SetMilk is also used to empty milk which sounds weird to me why set empty string if you ask for milk.

Should I instead also create the function emptyMilk. (asume the milk property is getting called alot)

```
public function emptyMilk() {
    $this->_milk = '';
}
```

Comment: For the record, `private string _getMilk() = '';` is not valid PHP.

Comment: Leaving aside what Jon Stirling pointed out, you can already empty the milk via setMilk(as you already pointed out), which is perfectly fine. Another function that's specifically called `emptyMilk` only adds complexity where complexity is really not needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A benefit of a seperate `emptyMilk()` function is that it allows you to use a special representation for an empty object, rather than exposing that to the callers.

```
private $is_empty = true;

public function getMilk(): string {
    if ($this->$is_empty) {
        throw new Exception("Empty milk");
    }
    return $this->$_milk;
}

public function setMilk(string $milk) {
    $this->is_empty = false;
    $this->_milk = $milk;
}

public function emptyMilk() {
    $this->is_empty = true;
    $this->_milk = null;
}

public function gotMilk(): boolean {
    return !$this->is_empty;
}
```

This allows you to use any value for `$_milk` rather than making one value special.

Comment: making milk an int or float would have been an better idea overall but I forgot to mention that. setting the emptyMilk() on $this->milk = 0 or 0.0 would allow us to just use the php function empty() which I quess would also work.